# Java List deserializing and returning an object gives Incompatible types error

Tags: java, serialization, compiler-errors, incompatibletypeerror, variable-types

I'm trying to deserialize a SetOfMembers list,and I want to take each Member object individually after deserializing in order to match the member name with a given String.

**"Incompatible types librarby.Member cannot be converted to Member where Member is a type-variable. Member extends Object declared in class SetOfMembers"**

The above error keeps appearing and I cannot make out the problem in my code.If you could explain to me what's wrong my code that'll be great. I used the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") but that's not helpful either.Please help. Thankyou

[image: Error]

Comment: Please include code as text.  Images cannot be searched, cannot be copied to text editors, and cannot be displayed in high quality fonts, making them less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess would be that

1. Top and bottom pieces of code are in different files
2. In the "top" file you imported (most probably by IDE suggestion) some other `Member` class such as `java.lang.reflect.Member` instead of your `library.Member` and thus you have this error.

So to fix this - check your imports section in the first tile.

If you really need both `Member` classes in the same file, you can still use fully qualified names. I bet following code would work anyway.

```
for(library.Member mem : Serialization.deserializeMembers())
```

Comment: 1.Top & bottom codes are in the same package "library" 2.No other Member class is imported 3.The given method solved the problem  Thankyou, I didn't know about an inbuilt Member class and ig it's the confusion here.

Comment: Re (2), the error message specifically refers to a *type*, which means a generic type parameter. Not an imported class.

Answer (score 1):

> Java List deserializing and returning an object gives Incompatible types error

No it doesn't.

1. This is a *compilation error* and it happens at *compile time* when *compiling the code*. **Not** when 'deserializing'.
2. The error isn't associated with deserialization at all: it's associated with an iteration.
3. It's an error, not a warning, so the annotation to suppress warnings is irrelevant.

The problem is clearly stated in the error message. As you haven't provided the full source code of the class or even the method in which it occurs, it is impossible to go further reliably.

However I will *guess* that:

- the first method is a member of `SetOfMember`
- `SetOfMember` is parameterized on `<Member extends Object>`.

... which would explain the error message completely. The problem being that the static method `deserializeMembers()` isn't actually generic. The fix is to genericize the `deserializeMembers()` method:

```
public static <Member extends Object> SetOfMember<Member> deserializeMembers() throws ...
```